# How to use types throughout Typescript project with dynamic imports and webpack chunks?

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack

I am trying to lazy load firebase in a Typescript project and want to have webpack put firebase to a separate chunk.
The code is:

```
let asyncFirestore: firebase.firestore.Firestore    
export default async () => {
  if (isNil(asyncFirestore)) {
    asyncFirestore = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunk-firebase" */ 'firebase/app').then(
      firebase => {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
        return firebase.firestore()
      }
    )
  }
  return asyncFirestore
}
```

From this module I want to use the lazy-loaded firebase in other modules. Unfortunately, firebase is not put to a separate webpack chunk at the moment. Separating other chunks in my project works correctly (`target` and `module` is set to `esnext` in tsconfig).

Currently I am doing `import firebase from 'firebase/app'` in other modules so I have access to things like `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

Do I need to avoid all those imports throughout my project that webpack would be able to put firebase to a separate chunk?
How would I then have access to firebase types throughout my project, e.g. for function return values?

Answer (score 0):

When you async import some module into your code, the types for that module are only visible within the scope of the variable that you assigned from the import.  In your case, `asyncFirestore` only has a specific type in the body of the anonymous function where it's declared.  Outside of that function, TypeScript sees it as `any`, because the calling code hasn't imported the type.

Also I think webpack isn't going to make it easy for you to dynamically know the final path of a module, since it will mangle the names of those modules in order to do its job.  Static imports don't have that problem, since webpack is able to determine what you want at compile time.

You might want to consider a completely different strategy.  One thing would be to introduce a module that deals entirely with Firebase, use static imports to get all the Firebase types for use within only that module, and only export other types of objects that result from Firebase APIs.

Comment: Thanks, if I would go for your different strategy approach, how would I then become webpack to separate out Firebase to a different chunk (different than the vendor-chunk)? I tried it but it's always getting bundled to the vendor-chunk.